# How to stop workflow transition names to be truncated? (JIRA 6.x)

Tags: java, jira

When a workflow transition text is longer than 25 characters, it is cut off after 25 chars (in the issue detail view) and full text is only available as mouse over.

For example
"eine kurz gewä hlte beze ichnung"
is truncated to
"eine kurz gewä hlte be..."

If anybody knows which source files have to be modified to get this fixed, I'd really like to know too ;-)

Thank you 
Peter

PS: The furthest I could find was the function "getAvailableActions" in TransitionLinkFactory.java which returns full text. So it gets truncated somewhere up the stack (jsp, js or some templates). CSS isn't it if one can trust firefox firebug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that. You can however modify the source code to increase the 25 chars limitation.

As mentionned in the following link (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-26746), you can :

- Download the source code of JIRA here : https://my.atlassian.com/download/source/jira
- Edit the file `IssueOperationsBarUtil.java` located at `atlassian-jira-x.x.x-source\jira-project\jira-components\jira-core\src\main\java\com\atlassian\jira\issue\util`. Change the methods `getLabelForLink()` and `getTitleForLink()` with the characters limit you want.
- Compile the code according to http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/How+to+Make+a+JIRA+Patch

Comment: Thank you Patrick, but this doesn't work anymore. This solution worked for JIRA 5.2 and although the files are still there, they seem not used anymore.